# Change the rownames of each dataset in a loop in R

Tags: r, dataframe, indexing

I am trying to change the index of my database. They have the same name, what changes is their number (dataset_id_1, dataset_id_2, ...., dataset_id_76). The datasets are in dataframe format and have 8 columns each.

I would like to change the current index of each (288 rows) into 740 to 1027.

I tried the following with no success:

```
range = c(740:1027)
    
for (i in 1:76) {
  rownames(dataset_id_[[i]]) = range
}
```

Do you know how to solve the problem?

Comment: Can you clarify the format of your data? Do you have a dataframe or matrix, where each row is named dataset_id_1, dataset_id_2, etc.? Or do you have a list of data, or something else? A small example would help as well.

Comment: Sure, sorry for that. all the dataset_id_i are dataframe with 8 columns each. Basically, they are sorted out by ID from a bigger dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work:

```
new_index <- 740:1027

for (i in 1:76) { 
   temp <- get(paste0('dataset_id_',i))
   rownames(temp) <- new_index
   assign(paste0('dataset_id_',i),temp)
}
```

You can get the name of each dataset through `paste0('data_set_id_',i)`, and then the `get` command allows you to access the actual dataframe from character name of the dataset. This object has its rownames modified, then the `assign` command re-assigns this new object to the original name.

However, there may be a more natural way to carry out the operation you want at the stage where you create each of these dataframes from the larger one.

Comment: Great, I'm happy to hear it!!